# Customizing TabBar in iphone

Tags: controller, tabbar, customizing

Hai

Can anyone guide me on How to customize the Tabbar such that each TabBarItem look like rounded button in Tabbar. and how to change the Tabbar Selection color.

Answer (score 1):

for the tabbar selection color there is no solution with UITabBarController. I ended up with for example 2 customize buttons with images that look like a tabbar.